# $\max_y$ notation

Tags: notation

Simple question, but googling $\max_y$ is taking me off track. What does $\min_y$ mean here? The value of $y$ that minimizes the integral?

$$\mathscr{l}(b^\prime) \equiv \min_y \int_{-L}^L \mathscr{l}(\,\left|\,y-m\,\right|)\,dF(m)$$

Comment: Not quite, the value of the integral (if y is the minimizer -- provided there is one)

Comment: @Alex thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome!